# SSH remote execute local script with args

Tags: linux, ssh, bash

I'm trying to execute a local script remotely using SSH for now here is how I'm doing it:

```
function remoteRun{

if [ $# -ls 2 ]; then
    usage()
    exit 1
fi
    ssh $1@$2 'bash -s' < $3
}
remoteRun user host script.sh
```

Now I'm trying to do the same thing but passing some arguments to the script.sh script.

Do you think that something like will work as expected?

```
remoteRun user host script.sh all step
```

If not, what is your best practice when you need to generate a script on Box A but execute them in Box B ?

Comment: mount box A via nfs on box B.

Comment: I can't use a mount or git as the runner is Jenkins which provide some parameters variables.

Comment: Why not send the script over(SCP/rsync) to that server and then execute the script?

Comment: As I said, my script use some jenkins variables, that's why I ask if args can be added on the 'classic' way to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function remoteRun()
{

   if [ $# -ls 2 ]; then
      usage()
      exit 1
   fi

cat << FOOF > /tmp/script
ls -l /var/log/
FOOF

   scp /tmp/script user@host:/tmp/
   ssh user@host "bash /tmp/script"
}

remoteRun user host script.sh
```